# Why does QGIS 2.2.0 displaying triangles instead of rectangles?

Tags: qgis

When displaying the demographic datas from INSEE (http://www.insee.fr/fr/themes/detail.asp?reg_id=0&ref_id=donnees-carroyees&page=donnees-detaillees/donnees-carroyees/donnees-carroyees-200m.htm), the results under qgis 2.2.0 is quite surprising :

- instead of rectangles I just see triangles in the bottom right corner (so covering half the surfaces)
- the same shape file opened with MapInfo 10.0 seems correct with all the rectangles correctly displayed and filled.

I can't see the reason of such a difference, it seems for me to be a bug of Qgis ..

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.  I see rectangles (I tested with the Martinique data) and opened in all QGIS versions from 2.0 to 2.3.

Comment: I have also tested the Metropole and Reunion data and it all loads as expected (rectangles).  I do not think this is a bug at all.  I think you have some corrupt data. This is more likely than such an obvious bug in the OGR implementation of the MIF format (which QGIS uses under the hood).  It's been stable for a long time! I recommend you try downloading the data again.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error, with 200m-rect-metropole. Saving to WGS84 leaves out the lower left point. Strangly, exporting geometry to csv contains the forth point as well.

It is not a bug of QGIS. I converted the mif to shp with ogr2ogr, and the triangles remain.

---

**EDIT**

Spatialite gui imports the data, but complains about Unclosed Rings.
In QGIS, `Polygons to lines`, then `Lines to polygons` closes the lines to rectangles:

[image]

So its more likely a bug in the data.

---

**EDIT 2**

Here is the beginning of the .mif file of Martinique:

```
Version 300
Charset "WindowsLatin1" 
Delimiter "," 
CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 24, "m", -63, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0 Bounds (-7746230.6469, -9998287.38389) (8746230.6469, 9998287.38389)
Columns 1
idk char(25 )
Data
Region 1
4
 728000.00 1592600.00
 729400.00 1592600.00
 729400.00 1596200.00
 728000.00 1596200.00
Region 1
4
 729600.00 1594400.00
 731600.00 1594400.00
 731600.00 1597000.00
 729600.00 1597000.00
Region 1
4
 731800.00 1596000.00
 733600.00 1596000.00
 733600.00 1597600.00
 731800.00 1597600.00
```

and the same after sanitizing with QGIS:

```
Version 300
Charset "Neutral"
Delimiter ","
CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 104, "m", -63, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0
Columns 1
  idk Char(25)
Data

Region 1
  5
728000 1592600
728000 1596200
729400 1596200
729400 1592600
728000 1592600
    Pen (1,2,0)
    Brush (1,0,16777215)
Region 1
  5
729600 1594400
729600 1597000
731600 1597000
731600 1594400
729600 1594400
    Pen (1,2,0)
    Brush (1,0,16777215)
Region 1
  5
731800 1596000
731800 1597600
733600 1597600
733600 1596000
731800 1596000
    Pen (1,2,0)
    Brush (1,0,16777215)
```

As you can see, QGIS writes 5 coordinate pairs, with the last identical to the first.

Comment: I have just loaded the Metropole data and it works perfectly for me.  I also suspect it must be bad data that has maybe been updated between when you downloaded your and when I downloaded mine (just now).

Comment: No chance on my side. Just loaded Martinique, and got the same triangles. Valmiera 32bit on XP. Exported as shp, and loaded into spatialite gui, it complains about Unclosed Rings.

Comment: Tested as well, with different results. Martinique data on Valmiera 64 OSX - triangles. Same data on QGIS 2.3-dev - rectangles!

Comment: The plot thickens!  I'm using 32bit on Windows 7.  I think the unclosed rings that Andre mentions is the key.  So, I still think that the data must be corrupt and QGIS is trying (and sometimes succeeding) in resolving the bad geometry.

Comment: In Dufour I get rectangles too, with the same project file and mif data.

Comment: I tried in 1.7.5 Wroclaw (on 64bit linux), using the MapInfo Interchange Format file directly and I get rectangles with all three datasets.  Looking through one of the mif files, it looks like it is following the format correctly  (http://resource.mapinfo.com/static/files/document/1074660800077/interchange_file.pdf) identifying lots of REGIONS with four points.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are seeing this bug:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9686
which was solved after the release of 2.2. **Try turning off simplification** for the layer - it's under the layer properties -> rendering tab.

Comment: This works for me, but using corrupt data (unclosed rings) may lead to other problems when you want to work with it.